# Flutter Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

`_stores` is giving me issue where if `value.stores` is null, I get the below `null` error. how to resolve this issue ? `null-safety` enabled as this project is `2.12.2` plus.

Code:

```
dynamic _stores = useProvider(
              storeViewModelProvider.select((value) => value.stores));
```

Code also tried :

```
dynamic _stores = useProvider(storeViewModelProvider
              .select((StoreViewModel? value) => value!.stores));
```

Error: `Null check operator used on a null value`

Can someone let me know what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

the attribute receiving useProvider has to be nullable.

after try this:

```
dynamic _stores = useProvider(
              storeViewModelProvider?.select((value) => value?.stores));
```

Comment: `The argument type 'ProviderListenable<Result<List<Store>>?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<dynamic>'.dart(argument_type_not_assig` is the error I get.